# need help My Library project has member problem

Tags: c

seems something is wrong. I've made a library project but some functions seem to be malfunctioning 
for example : When i choose my member list (Shown below) it exists the code.
in c version.

```
void addmember()
{
system("cls");
  // creating a FILE variable
  FILE *fptr;

  // creating a character variable
  char ch;

  // open the file in write mode
  fptr = fopen("username.txt", "w");

  // take user input
  printf("Enter your name: ");

ch = getchar();


    printf("Save any more?(Y / N):");
    if(getch()=='n')
        mainmenu();
    else
        system("cls");
       addmember();
}

void memberlist(){
    char ch;
     FILE *fptr;
    // open the file in read mode
  fptr=fopen("username.txt", "r");

  // display the content of the file
  printf("\nFile content:\n");
  while( (ch = getc(fptr)) != EOF ) {
    printf("%c", ch);
  }

  printf("\nEnd of file\n");

  // close file
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide details as to what *should* have happened under what circumstances and what *did* happen instead.

Comment: Calling addmember from inside addmember is not the way to run the routine again.  Use a loop instead of a recursive call.

Comment: My memberlist  won't display anything.

Comment: `getc()` returns `int` not `char`. It does this by intention.

Answer (score 1):

In *memberlist* do you check if the *fopen* works well ? Probably *fptr* is NULL

---

Several remarks in *addmember()* :

- *addmember* call itself at the end of its body, unconditionally, it is an infinite recursion
- for each recursive call you `fopen("username.txt", "w");` and that for nothing, but you never close the file
- only *one* character is read for the name, it's suspicious